# Which HTTP status codes are cacheable?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, cache-control

As stated in the title, which HTTP status codes are acceptable to cache as a browser? I did a quick search and did not find an authoritative answer.

Originally I thought it may only be `200` OK responses, but I couldn't find any evidence to support that thought.

Comment: Servers often use the `Cache-Control` response header to _explicitly_ indicate that the response should be cached (or not); [RFC 7234, Section 5.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.2) covers this header and its values and semantics.

Comment: Permanent redirects (301) are definitely cacheable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Short answer

According to the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the current reference for content and semantics of the HTTP/1.1 protocol, the following HTTP status codes are defined as *cacheable* unless otherwise indicated by the [method definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) or [explicit cache controls](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2):

- [`200` OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)
- [`203` Non-Authoritative Information](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.4)
- [`204` No Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)
- [`206` Partial Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1)
- [`300` Multiple Choices](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.1)
- [`301` Moved Permanently](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2)
- [`404` Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
- [`405` Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)
- [`410` Gone](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.9)
- [`414` URI Too Long](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.12)
- [`501` Not Implemented](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.2)

### Long answer

The [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) states the following regarding the HTTP status codes that are cacheable by default:

> [**6.1.  Overview of Status Codes**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.1)
>
> [...] Responses with status codes that are defined as cacheable by default
> (e.g., `200`, `203`, `204`, `206`, `300`, `301`, `404`, `405`, `410`, `414`, and `501` in
> this specification) can be reused by a cache with heuristic
> expiration unless otherwise indicated by the [method definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) or
> [explicit cache controls](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2); all other status codes are not
> cacheable by default. [...]

Once the HTTP status codes are extensible, recipient must note cache a response with an unrecognized status code:

> [**6.  Response Status Codes**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6)
>
> The status-code element is a three-digit integer code giving the
> result of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request.
>
> HTTP status codes are extensible.  HTTP clients are not required to
> understand the meaning of all registered status codes, though such
> understanding is obviously desirable.  However, a client MUST
> understand the class of any status code, as indicated by the first
> digit, and treat an unrecognized status code as being equivalent to
> the `x00` status code of that class, with the exception that a
> recipient MUST NOT cache a response with an unrecognized status code. [...]

The cache also depends on the HTTP method:

> [**4.2.3.  Cacheable Methods**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.3)
>
> Request methods can be defined as "cacheable" to indicate that
> responses to them are allowed to be stored for future reuse. In general, safe methods that
> do not depend on a current or authoritative response are defined as
> cacheable; this specification defines `GET`, `HEAD`, and `POST` as
> cacheable, although the overwhelming majority of cache
> implementations only support `GET` and `HEAD`.

Regarding the `POST` method, there's an important detail:

> [**4.3.3.  POST**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
>
> [...] Responses to `POST` requests are only cacheable when they include
> [explicit freshness information](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.1) [...]

For more details, check the [definition of each method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3).

### Additional resources

- [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234): Reference for caching in the HTTP/1.1 protocol
- [Check what browsers store in their cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38307389/1426227)

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-2) it is also allowed to cache responses that deliver another code than 200 (OK):

> [...]
> The most common form of cache entry is a successful result of a
> retrieval request: i.e., a 200 (OK) response to a GET request, which
> contains a representation of the resource identified by the request
> target (Section 4.3.1 of [RFC7231]).  However, it is also possible to
> cache permanent redirects, negative results (e.g., 404 (Not Found)),    incomplete results (e.g., 206 (Partial Content)), and responses to
> methods other than GET if the method's definition allows such caching
> and defines something suitable for use as a cache key.

So it's up to the browser developer what he wants to cache and what not.

Comment: Interesting, is there an agreed about standard about what status codes a browser should or should not cache, rather than just everything *can* be cached?

Comment: Not that I know of. In the end a cache is an optional feature. If you look at chapter 3 of the RFC you'll see that a cache doesn't need to cache any response at all:

_"3.  Storing Responses in Caches - 

  A cache MUST NOT store a response to any request"_

Comment: @twittfort You previous comment _is not accurate_. Quoting the full sentence: _A cache MUST NOT store a response to any request, **unless**: [an list of reasons]_. For more details regarding the HTTP status codes that are cacheable, have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39406969/1426227).