# Why 204 are not cached by OkHttp?

Tags: http, http-headers, okhttp, cache-control

Looking at the code in `CacheInterceptor` I see that response with the code 204 are not cached. Yet I believe 204 are cacheable as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398653/which-http-status-codes-are-cacheable)

We use `204` as a response to GET don't indicate an empty response and just recently noticed those are not cached.

Comment: Are there any explicit cache control headers or directives written for 204 response code to tell OkHttp not to cache 204?

Comment: No. The logic in the code simply skips caching for any request returning 204 regarding of the cache control headers

Comment: Can you post response headers?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why.

#### Why does the implementation behave like this?

Technically, 204s are skipped because the [`intercept` method will only cache responses if `promisesBody` returns `true`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/3ad1912f783e108b3d0ad2c4a5b1b89b827e4db9/okhttp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/cache/CacheInterceptor.kt#L135):

```
      if (response.promisesBody() && CacheStrategy.isCacheable(response, networkRequest)) {
        // Offer this request to the cache.
```

As you might expect, [`promisesBody` returns `false` for 204 responses](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/3ad1912f783e108b3d0ad2c4a5b1b89b827e4db9/okhttp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/http/HttpHeaders.kt#L214), *unless* they have a `Content-length` header, or `chunked` transfer encoding:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the response headers and status indicate that this response has a (possibly
 * 0-length) body. See RFC 7231.
 */
...
  val responseCode = code
  if ((responseCode < HTTP_CONTINUE || responseCode >= 200) &&
      responseCode != HTTP_NO_CONTENT &&
      responseCode != HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) {
    return true
  }

  // If the Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding headers disagree with the response code, the
  // response is malformed. For best compatibility, we honor the headers.
  if (headersContentLength() != -1L ||
      "chunked".equals(header("Transfer-Encoding"), ignoreCase = true)) {
    return true
  }

  return false
```

#### Why was this design used?

To justify this decision, it's possible that OkHttp's general use case for a cache is to save re-sending large payloads, rather than keeping round-trips to the absolute minimum. In addition, 204 is valid as a response to a `GET`, but more often used as a response to a `POST`; it's possible that the design reflects knowledge of this heuristic.

#### Why hasn't this changed?

Looking through [relevant issues](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22204%22+cache), there is one related to changing the default behaviour for certain status codes: [OkHttp cache-by-default status codes out of date](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1253):

> The spec wants these:
> 200, 203, **204**, 206, 300, 301, 404, 405, 410, 414, and 501

which resulted [in a test](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/3ad1912f783e108b3d0ad2c4a5b1b89b827e4db9/okhttp/src/jvmTest/java/okhttp3/CacheTest.java#L121):

```
    assertCached(true, 204);
```

However, due to the [configuration of the mock server](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/3ad1912f783e108b3d0ad2c4a5b1b89b827e4db9/okhttp/src/jvmTest/java/okhttp3/CacheTest.java#L166), the response used to test is:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 OK
...
Content-Length: 0
```

with exactly the unnecessary `Content-Length` that its own detection requires, and which a valid response should not include.

#### tl;dr

It's a bug, which nobody who's run into this case has reported.

Answer (score -2):

A 204 is returned when there is no content - "The server successfully processed the request and is not returning any content."

Therefore there is no data to cache if using the code to spec. If you are returning content/data than a 200 would be more appropriate.